# Tweaking Bash 'cd' and TAB completion to recognize spelling mistakes

Tags: bash, autocomplete, case-insensitive, cd

I was looking for a tweak to the cd command so that it recognizes spelling mistakes of directories and auto complete similar directory names.

Right now, I have settings that recognize the spelling mistakes of directory but does not auto complete them.

For directory spelling mistake correction I have this code in `~/.bashrc`:

```
shopt -s cdspell
```

Now it works in the following manner, suppose I have a directory called "trash"

```
vickey@home:~$ cd tras
trash
vickey@home:~/trash$ cd ..
vickey@home:~$ cd trasx
trash
vickey@home:~/trash$ pwd
/home/vickey/trash
vickey@home:~/trash$ 


vickey@home:~$ cd Trash
trash
vickey@home:~/trash$ pwd
/home/vickey/trash
```

But the problem I have is suppose I make a directory called Temp and do something like

```
vickey@home:~$ mkdir Temp
vickey@home:~$ cd temp
Temp
vickey@home:~/Temp$ cd ..
vickey@home:~$ cd te #and tab here
test/   textin/
```

it does not show `Temp` as an option. Is there anyway to make auto completion case insensitive?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Completion is a feature of `readline`.

You can enable case insensitive completion either by:

1) Adding to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

OR

2) Adding to your `/etc/inputrc`:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
```

Notes:

- `/etc/inputrc`, as @mak comments, effects all shells that use `readline`, and not just `bash`.
- This will make *all* completions case insensitive.

Comment: `inputrc` is used by shells that make use of `readline` like `bash`, `dash` and `zsh` (as opposed to `ksh`, `tcsh`, etc.). If you want to affect the behaviour of all your shells (not only `bash`), you need to edit `inputrc`. You can also locally edit `~/.inputrc` so you don't have to make changes in the global `/etc/inputrc`. .Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: echo "set completion-ignore-case on" | sudo tee -a /etc/inputrc